# Multiple order by SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a EAV database implemented in MySQL so when I say entity, you can read that as table. Since it's a non-relational database I cannot provide any SQL for tables etc but I'm hoping to get the conceptual answer for a relational database and I will translate to EAV SQL myself.

I'm building a mini stock market system. There is an "asset" entity that can have many "demand" and "offer" entities. The asset entity also may have many "deal" entites. Each deal entity has a "share_price" attribute. Not all assets have demand, offer or deal entities.

I want to return a list of offer and demand entities, grouped by asset i.e. if an asset has 2 offers and 3 demands only 1 result will show. This must be sorted by the highest share_price of deals attached to assets of the demand or offer. Then, the highest share_price for each demand or offer is sorted overall. If an asset has demands or offers but no deals, it will be returned with NULL for share_price.

So say the data is like this:

```
Asset 1 has 1 offer, 1 demand and 2 deals with share_price 7.50 and 12.00 
Asset 2 has 1 offer and 1 deal with share_price 8.00
Asset 3 has 3 offers and 3 demands and no deals
Asset 4 has no offers and no demand and 1 deal with share_price 13.00
```

I want the results:

```
Asset       share_price
Asset 1     12.00
Asset 2     8.00
Asset 3     null
```

Note: Asset 4 is not in the result set because it has no offers or demands.

I know this is a complex one with I really dont want to have to go to database more than once or do any array re-ordering in PHP. Any help greatly appreciated.

Some users want to see SQL I have. Here it is but this won't make too much sense as its a specialised EAV Database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT data.asset_guid, r.guid_two, data.share_price FROM (

    select rr.guid_one as asset_guid, max(msv.string) as share_price from market_entities ee

    join market_entity_relationships rr on ee.guid = rr.guid_two
    JOIN market_metadata as mt on ee.guid = mt.entity_guid
            JOIN market_metastrings as msn on mt.name_id = msn.id
            JOIN market_metastrings as msv on mt.value_id = msv.id

    where subtype = 6 and msn.string = 'share_price' and rr.relationship = 'asset_deal'
    group by                    
        rr.guid_one 
    ) data 

   left outer JOIN market_entities e on e.guid = data.asset_guid  
   left outer JOIN market_entity_relationships r on r.guid_one = e.guid  
   WHERE  r.relationship = 'trade_share' 
   GROUP BY data.asset_guid
```

Comment: I have written sql which returns assets and each asset's top share_price, and then this is ordered. It's EAV sql and very specialised. But the problem with my solution is I cannot get it to return assets with demands or offers available but no deals

Comment: Ok, when you post a question, post what you have so far for a variety of reasons: 1. people can see you've tried something and will not ask you what you've tried, 2. people can see what you're trying to do better, 3. people can see where you're going wrong, etc.

Comment: (in this case, that means translate what you have to sql, I do see your explanation at the top)

Comment: I will post SQL, but it wont make sense because so specialised!

Comment: the reality is that your query is really not very complex. Trust me, if you post sql, it will make sense. A lot more sense than what you have now.

Comment: @Colleen - I have posted the SQL above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without fully understanding your table structure (you should post that), looks like you just need to use a single `LEFT JOIN`, with `GROUP BY` and `MAX`:

```
SELECT a.assetname, MAX(d.share_price)
FROM asset a
   LEFT JOIN deal d ON a.AssetId = d.AssetId
GROUP BY a.assetname
ORDER BY MAX(d.share_price) DESC
```

I'm using the assumption that your Asset table and your Deal table have a common key, in the above case, AssetId.  Not sure why you'd need to join on Demand or Offer, unless those link to your Deal table.  Posting your table structure would alleviate that concern...

**--EDIT--**

In regards to your comments, you want to only show the assets which have either an offer or a demand?  If so, this should work:

```
SELECT a.assetname, MAX(d.share_price)
FROM asset a
   LEFT JOIN deal d ON a.AssetId = d.AssetId
   LEFT JOIN offer o ON o.AssetId = d.AssetId
   LEFT JOIN demand de ON de.AssetId = d.AssetId
WHERE o.AssetId IS NOT NULL OR de.AssetId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.assetname
ORDER BY MAX(d.share_price) DESC
```

This will only include the asset if it has at least an offer or at least a demand.

Comment: looks like he wants to filter out anything without offers since his results don't include Asset 4, but it's not entirely clear

Comment: @MattBusche -- I completely agree, very unclear :)  Where does the Demand table come into play -- possibly filter those out as well.  Can't know without OP providing additional details...

Comment: It's difficult to provide a schema, EAV schema never changes. I mainly use for tables - entity table, subtype table (this lists all entity types i.e. tables in a relational DB), metastrings and metadata.

Comment: Yes, Asset 4 should NOT be included in the result set because it has no demands or offers but it has deals. If it has 1 or more offers or demands, it would be included.

Comment: @sgeddes - thanks I will try this. Will take me a while to convert to EAV sql though but will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have 3 tables, assets, offers and shares, you can use a query like below.

```
SELECT asset, MAX(share_Price)
FROM assets
 INNER JOIN offers ON assets.id = offers.id //requires there are offers
 LEFT OUTER JOIN shares ON assets.id = shares.id // returns results even if no shares
GROUP BY asset
ORDER BY asset
```

Comment: Essentially there would be 4 tables in an relational DB - asset, demand, offer and deal.